# Gmock - How to set mock function parameter value from an input parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am using Gmock in my project. I have the following mock function.

```
  MOCK_METHOD2(helper,
     bool(const std::string&, std::string*));
```

Goal is to set value of parameter 1 to parameter 2 for all mock calls.

I did the following.

```
  std::string temp;

  EXPECT_CALL(
        MockObj,
        helper(_,_))
        .WillRepeatedly(
          DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&temp), //Save first arg to temp
                SetArgPointee<1>(temp), //assign it to second arg
                Return(true)));
```

However I see that parameter 2 is set to the original value of tmp rather than the value saved. Is there any other way to solve this? I want to make this EXPECT_CALL dynamic rather than doing SetArgPointee<1>("testval").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard actions do not support what you need. You will need to write a custom matcher:

```
ACTION(AssignArg0ToArg1) {
  *arg1 = arg0;
}
```

And you can then use it in combination with `Return(true)`. More information on custom actions can be found at https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/DesignDoc.md.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Ended up using a lambda with Invoke -       .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(
          Invoke([](const std::string& input,
                    std::string* output) {
            *output = input;
          }),
          Return(true)));

Comment: @balajiboss You comment was helpful. Consider constructing it into answer.